# Reaction of ketones with sodium amide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

> Find the product of the reaction of dimethyl ketone i.e. $\ce{CH3C(O)CH3}$ with $\ce{NaNH2}.$

Should I do nucleophilic addition and form the product in the picture?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are thinking would be substituted. There are no good leaving groups on dimethyl ketone. Given that sodium amide is a strong base, you should ask yourself how dimethyl ketone can act as an acid, and what reactions could occur from there. I'll give you a hint: there should be a nucleophilic addition step.

Comment: Sodamide is a strong base and so I  believe it will deprotonate any organic compound and form a sodium salt of that organic compound.

Comment: try thinking on 1) $\ce{2*CH3COCH3}$ in presence of soda amide and 2) ofcourse what @ringo said is also true.

Comment: https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/acetone-ch3-coch3-undergoes-following-acid-base-reaction-sodium-amide-nanh2-please-note-pk-q9919579

Comment: Addition is irrelevant here.

Comment: @ayush not *that* nucleophilic addition step. Another base will be formed before any addition occurs

Comment: It's just aldol condensation.